# No such file or directory: 'builtup/build0.jpg'

Tags: python

When trying to plot the first 9 images in my satellite images folder which I prepared it and type my folder path ‘buildup’ it says:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: please paste the code here, not the image

Comment: What don't you understand? The file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like..

```
import os
filename = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 
    folder, 
    'build{}.jpg'.format(i)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute path to the image.

```
    import os
    absolute_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'builtup', 'build', str(i) + '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over all files in the given folder and check, if they are .jpg/.JPG

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.image import imread
import os

#also try with full path:
folder = '/builtup/'

i=0
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith('.jpg') or file.endswith('.JPG'):
        if i <= 8:
            pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
            image = imread(os.path.join(folder,file))
            pyplot.imshow(image)
            i=i+1

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I have fixed the error by renaming the images name from[ build (0).jpg] to  [build.0.jpg]